# What is the name of this circle/quadrilateral shape?

Tags: geometry

Basically, it is a circular shape with the upper chord portion and lower chord portion removed. Both chord portions are parallel and having the same size. Sometimes you can see this shape at the US electricity wall socket. Is there a specific name for this shape?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/74oa6.png

Comment: The US electricity wall socket example can be seen here: http://www.boardmantwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/wall-outlet.jpg

Comment: Just found another example in the image here: https://im01.itaiwantrade.com/aa6a4f4e-d1b3-4ef8-832b-a2e801ad376e/Oblong_Solid_Type_Trimming_Die_TiN_Coated-480x480.JPG

I'm looking for the name of the shape of the hole.